# implicit derivative of a function with x=x(y)

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

Take the implicit differentiation of the $F(x,y)= y- xy^{2}-x^{2}+1$ with respect to $y$, where $x=x(y)$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Just differentiate each term of the equation, using the chain rule and product rule, and keeping in mind that it is $x$ that is considered a function of $y.$

Comment: i found the answer, $f_{y}=1 - 2yx - \frac{dx}{dy}(y^{2}+2x)$ but im not sure if this is the last step

Comment: @anonymous The symbol $=$ is missing. It should be there somewhere.